# Splitting a number in c++

Tags: c++, function, split, numbers

I have to make a program which does the following: The input should be `n` (n>1). If n = 5, the following should happen:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 4
2 3
```

As you can see, there are no two of the same lines and the order is strict - from lowest number to highest.

I've got a code which, in the same case, outputs this:

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
2 2 1
3 1 1
3 2
4 1
```

As you can see the order is reversed which is unintended. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

unsigned *mp;

void print(unsigned length)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) printf("%u ", mp[i]);
    printf("%u\n", mp[length]);
}

void devNum(unsigned n, unsigned pos)
{
    unsigned k;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        if (n != k)
        {
            mp[pos] = k;
            if (mp[pos] <= mp[pos - 1])
            {
                devNum(n - k, pos + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mp[pos] = k;
            if (pos > 1 && mp[pos] <= mp[pos - 1]) print(pos);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned n;
    cin >> n;
    mp = new unsigned[n + 1];
    mp[0] = n + 1;
    devNum(n, 1);
    delete[] mp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please comment/explain your code: what is it supposed to be doing along the way.

Comment: @ScottHunter I already said that my english is bad so I can not explain it very well. Wel... any number n (n > 1) can be made by combining some lower numbers. In my example 5=1+1+1+1+1 or 1+1+1+2 or .... 1+4 or 2+3.. The program should output all those possibilities without repeating two of the same kind in a very strict order (from lower to higher number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: I rewrote `devNum()` and `main()` to fit the new spec. Note that I changed the value filled in `mp[0]`.**

```
void devNum(unsigned n, unsigned pos)
{
    for (mp[pos] = mp[pos-1]; mp[pos] <= n; ++mp[pos])
    {
        if(mp[pos] != n)
        {
            devNum(n - mp[pos], pos + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            if (pos > 1) print(pos);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned n;
    cin >> n;
    mp = new unsigned[n+1];
    mp[0] = 1;
    devNum(n, 1);
    delete [] mp;
    return 0;
}
```

---

(For the old spec)

Change

```
void devNum(unsigned n, unsigned pos)
{
    unsigned k;
    for (k = n; k >= 1; k--)
    /* ... */
```

into

```
void devNum(unsigned n, unsigned pos)
{
    unsigned k;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        if (n != k)
        {
            mp[pos] = k;
            if (mp[pos] <= mp[pos - 1])
            {
                devNum(n - k, pos + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mp[pos] = k;
            if (pos > 1 && mp[pos] <= mp[pos - 1]) print(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I check for `pos > 1` before calling `print()` to avoid the single `5`.

To remove the fixed `MAX` limit, you could allocate `mp` dynamically in `main()`. That is, change

```
const int MAX = 100;
unsigned mp[MAX + 1];
```

into

```
unsigned *mp;
```

and write `main()` as

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned n;
    cin >> n;
    mp = new unsigned[n+1];
    mp[0] = n + 1;
    devNum(n, 1);
    delete [] mp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot ! I can't describe how helpful you were ! Though I've made a slight mistake in my question... I should get the lines of the raws in reversed order as well... starting from the lowest to the highest.. I'll change my wanted output in my question ASAP. Could you help me for that as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Damn it.. Should I make another question or something?

Comment: @user3236732 Rewritten for the new question spec.

Comment: `mp[0] = 1;` line gives an unhandled exception: access violation writing location. When I input something and click enter the console freezes :?

Comment: @user3236732 I didn't notice that you've replaced `mp` by a pointer. I've edited it again. This time it should work as shown in http://ideone.com/pbBgFy